# Attribute set is missing after upgrade to magento 2.2.9 from 2.2.6 which is migrated website from magento 1.x

Tags: attribute-set, data-migration, magento-upgrade, magento2.2.9

I had migrated Magento 1 website to Magento 2.2.6, so after some days i had upgraded my Magento version to 2.2.9, after upgrade i can see that my attributes sets are missing and when i checked into databases eav_attribute_set and this table is empty.

Any one have face this type of issue. Please Help

Comment: If you have the backup of your DB, then you need to recover these tables. or put the whole DB back and try to migrate again with the logs.

Comment: Check if eav_attribute_set table is skipped/ignored in map.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Try to migrate again after removing below from map.xml if you are using magento-data-migration tool.

```
<ignore>
   <document>eav_attribute_set</document>
</ignore>
```

or

Table structure of table in M1 & M2 are same so you can also insert same M1' eav_attrubte_set table data to M2's eav_attribute.